# django image gallery showing no images

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

[how-to-build-a-photo-gallery-with-django-part-1](https://engineertodeveloper.com/how-to-build-a-photo-gallery-with-django-part-1/)

[how-to-build-a-photo-gallery-with-django-part-2](https://engineertodeveloper.com/how-to-build-a-photo-gallery-with-django-part-2/)

This is an excellent tutorial for learning how to make an image gallery in django.
As it suggests, I have recreated page step by step here link: [image gallery](http://singhaidotnish.pythonanywhere.com/photo_gallery/pet/01/)

I am adding images to sql table yet the path it's referring to is /photo_gallery/pet/01/media/image/kitty/gallery/.....

The image page is blank because it does not find image in the path. I don't know where it is stored.

**Error log :**

```
Not Found: /photo_gallery/pet/01/media/image/kitty/gallery/kitty10.jpeg
Not Found: /photo_gallery/pet/01/media/image/kitty/gallery/kitty11.jpeg 
Not Found: /photo_gallery/pet/01/media/image/kitty/gallery/kitty14.jpeg
```

this path is not being set anywhere then could it be django's way of storing it.

How does one ensure the page shows all images for a given pet ( in this context ) .

Template :

```
{% load sass_tags %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/simplelightbox/2.7.0/simple-lightbox.css" integrity="sha512-8WAX0xL/cHZ38RXoX2gtuqkAwmDVAzGwoFVmHvn46IDHGWOjTHx0vcl9OapNrfOzpFtql0SNkv+0y0b5Fm8ZkA==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
        <link href="{% sass_src 'pages/scss/main.scss' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <title>Gallery</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <h1>Gallery</h1>
                    <section class="photo_gallery">
                        {% for gallery_image in pet.images.all %}
                        <a href="{{ gallery_image.image.url }}"><img src="{{ gallery_image.image.url }}" alt="" title="" /></a>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </section>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/simplelightbox/2.7.0/simple-lightbox.min.js" integrity="sha512-ZajFBgnksNp8Rj+AbmYe8ueOu45HiSjtf3QpqnRbHlq719m6VK0FkbYIqQ8wEnlVuJ1i9pC+z6Z9ewmDnUTMCg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
        var gallery = new SimpleLightbox('.photo_gallery a');
    </script>

</html>
```

Comment: It is hosted on Pythonanywhere, so have you run `python manage.py collectstatic` and set the media url ?

Comment: show your template code

Comment: @Prakhar, collectstatic should work with static_root. ?

Comment: @nish collectstatic will collect all your static files to the specified directory on pythonanywhere, it serves static files from there only. so please check specified directory has those static files. To check : go to `web tab on pythonanywhere`, scroll down to `static files section`, and verify if files are there or not